# PHP code not working in a Form which is used for javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working with a form which uses Javascript for a process. When i try to read the textbox value in form with PHP, It's not showing output.

My code is

HTMLCode is

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="staff.php" onSubmit=" return questiontable()" >


<div class="form-group">
     <label for="qscount">Number of Questions: </label>
        <input type="number" name="qscount"  class="form-control" id="qscount" style="width:150px;" placeholder="No of questions"> <br> 
        </div>          
              <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" id="gobtn" onClick="return disable()"  >Go</button> <br>
            <p id="btnhide">  </p>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function questiontable()
        {           
            var qs = document.getElementById("qscount").value;
            var count;
            for(count=1; count<=qs; count++)
                {                   

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  += '<br><font style="font-size: 20px">'+ count+'. <input class="textboxtest" style="width:850px;" type="text" name=" q'+ count +' " placeholder="Question "><br>' ;      
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  +='<br><input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" name="a'+count+'" value="c1"> <input class="testbox" type="text" name="o'+count+'1" placeholder="Option 1">';  
    return false;
        }   

</script>
```

PHP Code is

```
        <?php
 if (isset($_POST['qscount'])){
    echo $_POST['qscount'];
 } 
 ?>
```

I want to use this qscount value in another php page. How to get this textbox value in PHP and use it in another page ?

Comment: By returning false you are telling form not to submit So you need to return true at some point when you are sure you have validated everything.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function() should return true, since you are using return function() in onclick attribute of button type=submit

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function questiontable()
    {           
        var qs = document.getElementById("qscount").value;
        var count;
        for(count=1; count<=qs; count++)
            {                   

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  += '<br><font style="font-size: 20px">'+ count+'. <input class="textboxtest" style="width:850px;" type="text" name=" q'+ count +' " placeholder="Question "><br>' ;      
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  +='<br><input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" name="a'+count+'" value="c1"> <input class="testbox" type="text" name="o'+count+'1" placeholder="Option 1">';  
    }   

 return true;
 }
 </script>
```

This will continue the form posting onclick of the button

If you are trying to create the number of questions on click dynamically using javascript,

then use  syntax to call questionTable

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="gobtn" onClick="javascript:return questiontable()"  >Create Questions</button>
```

Remove

```
onSubmit=" return questiontable()"
```

from the form

Now when the question table is rendered, please show the button type="submit"

```
<button type=submit value="Go" name="cmdGo">Go</button>
```

to trigger form submission

Hope it helps!

Comment: If i use return true, Javascript table is just showing for a second and getting hide.

Comment: The form gets posted to staff.php. Also can you tell me where is element having id as demo located. If its not available then the javascript will break